# React Native: Making a status indicator. Style a component, or use an image?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of items that can be active, idle (if the current time doesn't match their active time), or off all together. I want to make a little gem like icon that reflects their current status in the list view.

In web I would just use CSS to make a little shape with green, red, or orange. Are there any disadvantages to just styling an empty view in React Native where I should make them images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in using styles views as simple icons or indicators and this might actually help avoid some overheads( like time to display the image or memory for the images over the top of my head). The only downside I can think of is that it won't give you the same precision as images would.